# flip image using jquery on button click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a simple drag and drop web application using jquery.

everything so far works as it should.
now what I am trying to do is to add a button to the page so when its clicked, it will `FLIP` the selected image and I am not having any luck with at all.

**I have created a jsfiddle so you can see it for yourself:**  http://jsfiddle.net/7btkn17q/8/

drag and drop a book image onto the box bellow it and click once inside it, and you will see a button appear at the top of it which says flip.

I need to use that button to flip the ***selected*** image.

for that I used this:

```
$('#flip').click(function(e){

    if( $(e.target).closest(".drag").length > 0 ) {
        $(e.target).closest("#droppable .drag img").css('border', 'solid 5px #000');


    }

    });
```

but this does not have any affect on the image(s) at all. I know that the code above is not for flipping the image(s). i just created that code as a test to see if I can access the image(s) on button click with no luck.

could someone please advise on this?

EDIT:

EVEN  though I thought this would work, it didn't and I am so confused on why it didn't work:

```
    $('#flip').click(function(e){
    if($(e.target).closest(".drag").length > 0 ) {
    $(e.target).closest("#droppable .drag").find('img').css('border','5px solid #000');
    }       
});
```

Second Edit:

I've tried to use the `remove()` function to see if i could get the `img` and somewhat I could  make it work but similar to the answer bellow, it will remove *ALL* the img's instead of removing the *selected* only:

```
$(e.target).parent().siblings(".drag" ).find(".img" ).remove();
```

is there any way to apply the CSS or remove() to the `selected element` only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When selecting an image, you can set a class to it. Let's add `selected` to it.
When selecting another image we just remove the `selected` class from other elements and add it to the one we just selected.

[Here's my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7btkn17q/10/)

Another problem I noticed, was that you were trying to test this by changing the border of the selected element. When you click the `flip` button, the image gets unselected and the border is changed to `medium none` (Remember, firebug/devtools are your friends.).
So I changed it to change the `outline` css property to see that the button works.

You also might want to update from jQuery 1.6 as the event handling is so much easier with the `.on()` function.

Answer (score 0):

'.closest()' only travels up the DOM tree; you'll need to do something like this to target the images:

```
$('#flip').click(function(e){
    if( $(e.target).parent().siblings(".drag").length > 0 ) {
    $(e.target).parent().siblings(".drag").find('img').css('border','5px solid #000');
    }       
});
```

updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7btkn17q/9/

Comment: Your code applies the border CSS to all the images at the same time. I need to apply the CSS to selected image only. so one at a time.